# Dreamweaver throwing an error in Jquery script

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to use the following in the head on my page, but when I am putting it in using Dreamweaver I am getting errors, but I am not sure where the errors are ?.

```
<script>
$('.multiselect, this).each(function(key, val){  $(this).multiselect({     
noneSelectedText:''+$(this).attr('title')+''  });     
});
</script>
```

Comment: How about missed quote in the first `$(...)`?

Comment: You've got an unterminated string literal in there:  `$('.multiselect, this)`.  Probably you want `$('.multiselect', this)`.

Comment: `''+$(this).attr('title')+''` - what are empty strings used here for?

Comment: Thanks thats got it !, it was a missing '   :-)